# Why is the iCloud Photostream option not available in iOS preferences?

Tags: ios, photo-stream

My iPhone 4 runs iOS 5.1.1.

When I go to settings > iCloud, the Photostream option is not available.
I've tried to restore my phone, but the option is still not available.

[image]

How can I activate this setting when it's missing from the preference?

Comment: Same problem here with my iPhone 4S on Sprint...both the Photo Stream and Documents options are not available in Settings -> iCloud. My wife also has an iPhone 4S on Verizon with no issues.

Comment: Can you delete this account from the phone and perhaps try another account? Also - the troubleshooting article mentions that you can sign into iCloud on a computer and reset all the photos. Can you at least see the reset option if you don't want to reset everything to a clean slate and try again setting it up on the device. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486

Comment: thanks for that. unfortunately it didn't solve my issue. I'm thinking: this is my professional phone. Is there a way for my employer to lock down this feature through the application of a profile (I know they use one e.g. for setting password policy)?

Comment: Pierre...that might be it (my phone is a work-supplied as well). Maybe they're limiting our bandwidth usage?? I'll ping my tech support today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looked a little closer at my settings....
Settings -> General -> Profiles -> [Work Profile] -> More Details -> Disable Documents in the Cloud, iCloud backup, Photo Stream.

There's my answer, my company supplied configuration that was loaded on the phone limits this option.

C'est la vie...

Comment: Great answer - profiles can restrict a ton of options.

Comment: Bingo! I have the same limitation. Thanks a ton for your investigations!

Answer (score -4):

Photos are no longer in the CAMERA.  They are in the Photos. (the blue background with the flower).